# submitting two forms one after another

Tags: python, django-forms

I am working on my first django webaite, I am trying to submit two forms one after the other.
Here is the views.py :

```
def home(request):
  import json
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = MajorForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        url = 'http://www.mysite.com:8082'
        dataout = {'my':'data'}
        headers = {'content-type':'application/json'}
        r = requests.post(url,data=json.dumps(dataout),headers=headers)
        return collector(request)
    else:
        return HttpResponse("thnx")
  else:
    form = MajorForm()
  return render(request,'index.html',{'form':form})

def collector(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ContactForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
       return HttpResponse("thanx")
    else:
       return HttpResponse("not valid")
  else:
    form = ContactForm();
  return render(request,'collector.html',{'form':form})
```

So the first view calls the second view. The first form works fine, and the second form is also displayed fine, but submitting the second form does not work at all ( I was never able to get to `form.is_valid path`). Maybe this entire approach of calling one view from another is not correct? What would be the right one?

Answer (score 0):

Please indent your code correctly. Also you are missing an else in the collector function when the request.method is not POST.

Comment: Right, but the problem is that in the collector function it never gets into the path when the request is not POST. It always shows 'not valid' path. I think the request sent to collector function has POST in it from the previous submit. I don't know how to get around this..